# MPS - accessing sources in Idea as MPS models from MPS plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, mps

Is it possible from MPS-enabled plugin in IDEA to access (for read/write) project's source code as baseLanguage (or whatever) source models? I want to be able to do refactorings to a source code in IDEA based on models in that MPS-enabled plugin.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you would like to represent existing java source code as MPS models and then do refactorings to them?

Comment: Kolja, yes, in such manner that refractoring affects project code and not only MPS model

Answer (score 2):

Currently the is no possibility of editing java source code as MPS root (in projectional editor).

But here what can be done:

- Any java source code in module with MPS facet will be loaded as java stubs by MPS plugin, so you can use it in MPS code. And vice versa - you can use baseLannguage classes from java source code directly.
  To use java source code in MPS root you need to import stub model (package with classes) either from model settings (*F4* on model or package with per-root model) or using **Add Model Import by Root** (*Ctr+R*) from MPS root editor.
- There are two types of models: default and [per-root](https://mps-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207189985-Using-mps-file-per-root-in-intellij), where second one creates separate file for each MPS root. As result it you can mix MPS roots and java source files in the same package.
- Use **Convert Java to MPS** action on java class to transform it to MPS root in per-root model.

Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though I'm already aware of such possibility, but what I was thinking of is some small refactoring language.